# What is the minimum flow required for a pressure washer?

Tags: pressure-washer

I would like to buy a Karcher pressure washer and connect it to a spring water 
source, not city water.

I didn't measure the throughput yet, but it is less than city water for sure.

I would like to know what is the minimum input flow (liters/h ?) required for
a Karcher to work ?

Same question regarding water pressure: what would be the minimum required ?
Maybe it is not so relevant since the Karcher will pressurized it ;)
Moreover I don't know how to measure water pressure easily.

Any help would be appreciated :) Otherwise I can also try... And see how it
goes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most consumer pressure washers require a feed at typical municipal pressure and at a flow rate of more than the washer's output.  Karcher appears to be an exception.

[This video](https://pressurewasherreviewer.co.uk/use-karcher-pressure-washer-bucket/) claims that their units can draw the water they need from a static source, like a drum or tank of water or a pool, using a siphon hose.  That water isn't under significant pressure (its own weight), but nothing limits the flow in that scenario.  If you feed it from a piped source, that source must be sufficient to feed it as fast as it needs it.

I would verify the requirements for the specific model you're considering.  The specs should tell you the input requirements, or you can check with Karcher customer service for an official answer.